# Check preconditions when creating a CloudFormation Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to check preconditions and raise an error if some preconditions are not met on creation of a CloudFormation Stack?

For example, I want to restrict creation of a Stack to us-east-1 Region.  Although the following code works, the `[FAILED]` message contradicts the final Status of the Stack, which is always `CREATE_COMPLETE` regardless of regions:

```
{
  "Conditions": {
    "ValidRegion": {
      "Fn::Equals": [
        {
          "Ref": "AWS::Region"
        },
        "us-east-1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Description": "Certificate for Global services",
  "Outputs": {
    "GlobalCertificateArn": {
      "Description": "Certificate ARN",
      "Value": {
        "Fn::If": [
          "ValidRegion",
          {
            "Ref": "GlobalCertificate"
          },
          "[FAILED] Failed to create certificate for Global services.  Create this stack in us-east-1."
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Parameters": {
    "Domain": {
      "Description": "Domain name of this website",
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "GlobalCertificate": {
      "Condition": "ValidRegion",
      "Properties": {
        "DomainName": {
          "Ref": "Domain"
        }
      },
      "Type": "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to raise an error?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your example, it would be better to use the AWS pseudo-parameters. Just create a condition that checks whether "AWS::Region" equals us-east-1.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html

Can't really come up with a generic way to check everything, it depends on the situation. For example, if you're dealing with parameters, you can use a regex or set allowed values:

"Parameters" : {
  "InstanceTypeParameter" : {
    "Type" : "String",
    "Default" : "t2.micro",
    "AllowedValues" : ["t2.micro", "m1.small", "m1.large"],
    "Description" : "Enter t1.micro, m1.small, or m1.large. Default is t1.micro."
  }
}

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

Or you could combine mappings, which contain your desired values, with conditions.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html

Lots of possibilities. :)